# WPF DataTrigger on PropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, datatrigger

I have a view model property that is set to runtime objects. I want to trigger an animation whenever this property changes, so I was planning to use `DataTrigger`. However, `DataTrigger` obviously has the requirement for a `Value` property--one that I don't know at design-time.

Is there a built in way to trigger an animation whenever a value changes, regardless of what it changes into?

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421418/wpf-datatrigger-on-any-data-binding-change) but I was wondering if there was anyway to do it purely in XAML. Otherwise I figure I could probably fire an event from my View Model whenever the property changes and listen to that.

Comment: Create bindings on the DataTrigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method would be to create a User Control with a dependency property and then bind both of your other properties to that i.e. one at compile time and the other at runtime. Alternatively you could use an Attached Behaviour to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Can add a boolean property and trigger the animation based on the bool property. Whenever the original property changes, set and reset the boolean property so that it triggers the animation and also goes back to default value for next notification.