# WPF flash when fill/background color changes

Tags: c#, wpf, colors

I would like to have an ellipse fill "flash"(turn white instantly and then return to the new color) whenever databound fill color changes. This is what I got so far:

```
<ctrls:NotifyEllipse Fill="{Binding Cluster.Brush, Converter={StaticResource CloneConverter}}" Width="10" Height="10" >
  <ctrls:NotifyEllipse.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ctrls:NotifyEllipse}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ctrls:NotifyEllipse.FillChanged">
          <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard AutoReverse="True">
              <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ctrls:NotifyEllipse.Fill).Color" To="White" Duration="0:0:1" />
            </Storyboard>
          </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </ctrls:NotifyEllipse.Style>
</ctrls:NotifyEllipse>
```

where `ctrls:NotifyEllipse` is `UserControl` containing only ellipse, with dependency property `Fill` and routed event `FillChanged` - similar [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3441670/3096657). The color changed detection part works great, however the flash part(obviously) does not work as I would like to: it first changes fill color to the new color, than slowly turns white and at the end turns back to new color.
As mentioned above, the goal is to "flash" - turn white instantly and then return to new color. 
Please note that there is databinding on the Fill so having two animations one instant and other slow is not possible simply because I dont know which color to return to:

```
<Storyboard>
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ctrls:NotifyEllipse.Fill).Color" To="White" Duration="0:0:0" />
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ctrls:NotifyEllipse.Fill).Color" To="???" Duration="0:0:1" />
</Storyboard>
```

*bonus points:* Flash to white not instantly but fast and keep original color until the full white was reached and then turn from white to new color slowly, this would be ideal solution but I am afraid it would require a lot of custom animation code. Flash as described above is sufficient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just start the ColorAnimation from `White`:

```
<Storyboard>
    <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Fill.Color"
                    From="White" Duration="0:0:1" />
</Storyboard>
```

---

For completeness, my NotifyEllipse class looks like this:

```
public class NotifyEllipse : Shape
{
    static NotifyEllipse()
    {
        FillProperty.AddOwner(typeof(NotifyEllipse), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
            (o, e) =>
            {
                if (e.NewValue != e.OldValue)
                {
                    ((NotifyEllipse)o).RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(FillChangedEvent));
                }
            }));
    }

    public static readonly RoutedEvent FillChangedEvent =
        EventManager.RegisterRoutedEvent(
            "FillChanged", RoutingStrategy.Bubble,
            typeof(RoutedEventHandler), typeof(NotifyEllipse));

    public event RoutedEventHandler FillChanged
    {
        add { AddHandler(FillChangedEvent, value); }
        remove { RemoveHandler(FillChangedEvent, value); }
    }

    protected override Geometry DefiningGeometry
    {
        get { return new EllipseGeometry(new Rect(RenderSize)); }
    }
}
```

Comment: It was this simple? I literally spent a day on solving this... thanks alot